# How to move the sub-menu drop-down items towards right on hover in Bootstrap 4.1?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, bootstrap-4

I am working on a [website](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) in which the **submenu dropdown items appears at the bottom** as shown below.

[image]

The HTML/CSS code which I have used for that are as follows:

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<!-- 
   <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/prostore';" class="btn btn-default">Hello World</button>
    -->
<li class="menu-item nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   main menu
   </a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">about</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">blog</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">contact us</a>
      <div class="submenu-item">
         <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle dropright" href="#" id="navbarDropdownSubMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         Social
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownSubMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">T</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">U</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">V</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">W</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.menu-item:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

/* makes sub-menu S open on hover */
.submenu-item:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the HTML/CSS above so that **if we hover on Social, the drop-down items T, U, V and W are displayed towards the right similar to [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/ji5ijk6yJ4)**

Comment: I've been playing with `dropright` and I can get it to work for your "main menu" but sub-navs are not behaving for dropright.  I'm going to continue to see what combination will work but I have to call it a day for now.  GL and I'll see what I can find - it's an interesting puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to bootstrap 4 you would use pull-right, but since 4 they changed the pull-right to float-(sm,md,lg,xl)-(left,right,none). So I would try float-sm-right. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities

Comment: Can you let me know where exactly I need to make changes in the code ? I have created the [link](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) for that so that its easy for you to visualize.

Comment: Add text-align: right to .submenu-item:hover > .dropdown-menu. You dont have to set anything to float.

Comment: text-align:right doesn't seems to make it work. If you check this [link](https://www.codeply.com/go/ji5ijk6yJ4), I want something like that.

Comment: BS4 introduced `drop-right`. [See this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#dropright)

Comment: @fnostro can you give me a pointer how can I replicate that in my code above ?

Comment: @user5447339 Im sorry I must of misunderstood you. Thought you want the text to be aligned to the right, but you want the dropdown menu to drop to the right. Yes use the drop-right code from bootstrap. Add dropright to this line of code <li class="menu-item nav-item dropdown dropright">.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code from bootstrap website.

```
<div class="bd-example">
  <div class="btn-group dropright">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropright
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="right-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(108px, 0px, 0px);">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group dropright show">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
  Split dropright
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropright</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="right-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(153px, 0px, 0px);">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see this is not in your code

```
x-placement="right-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(108px, 0px, 0px);"
```

and

```
<div class="btn-group dropright show">
```

try adding these to your code.